# Reported speech in this case

Tags: reported-speech

Tom said the following.

> We have to win this game.

Will the subject change in the reported speech?

> Tom said to me that they had to win that game.

or

> Tom said to me that we had to win that game.

Comment: It simply depends on context. English does not distinguish between inclusive _we_ (you, me and maybe some others) and exclusive _we_ (me and some others). So it all depends on what Tom meant exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on whether or not you were included in Tom's *we*.

If his *we* included you then the reported speech should use *we*; but if his *we* did not include you then it should use *they*.

If you are reporting what he said and you are unsure if he had meant to include you, you can phrase it differently.

> Tom said to me that "we" had to win that game. But I'm not sure if he was talking about me too.